# Docker service restart without order sequence when using docker-compose depends_on

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to setup a [Sonarqube](https://hub.docker.com/_/sonarqube/) service in docker for windows and use mysql as database.

I am using below compose file, and using compose-file `depends_on` to control start up order:

**db**->**sonarqube**

But when docker services/windows restart, containers start up with no sequence.
Which will take error when sonarqube trying to connect mysql but mysql service didnt startup first.

```
version: '3'

services:
  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube:6.5
    container_name: sonarqube
    restart: always
    environment:
      - SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:mysql://db:3306/sonar?useSSL=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
      - SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=sonar
      - SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=sonar
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
      - 9002:9002
      - 9092:9092
    volumes:
      - ../../volumes/data/sonarqube/conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf
      - ../../volumes/data/sonarqube/data:/opt/sonarqube/data
      - ../../volumes/data/sonarqube/extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
      - ../../volumes/data/sonarqube/lib/bundled-plugins:/opt/sonarqube/lib/bundled-plugins
    depends_on:
      - db

  grafana:
    container_name: grafana
    image: grafana/grafana
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ../../volumes/data/grafana-storage:/var/lib/grafana
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db

  # mysql service for sonarqube & grafana
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: sonar-mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=sonar
      - MYSQL_USER=sonar
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=sonar
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Password1
      - MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET=13421772800
    volumes:
      - ../../volumes/data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    command: mysqld --max_allowed_packet=80M --federated --event_scheduler=1
```

> After reading some of docker-compose official document,
>   They said the best way is to check the application code, like updating entrypoint scripts using waiting for other service online then start application.

It's the right way I think, but I still want to know if there is any way we can control containers startup sequence when docker service restart?

Thanks.

Comment: As you said, the only way to control this (after restarts) is to use a wait-for-it implementation like it's here: https://github.com/lvthillo/docker-ghost-mysql/blob/master/ghost/wait-for-it.sh In this example the ghost container will only start after a succesful connection to mysql